# print the folder name of a python script

Tags: python

How can I print the folder name of my python script?

Let us say I entered this in the terminal:

```
python sample-folder/script.py
```

I looking for a code that will print 'sample-folder'

**P.S.**

I can't seem to return this using the os library

Comment: `os.path.split(__file__)[0]`?

Comment: The problem with your command is it is not dynamic.. If I tried running python 'x/sample-folder/script' then it will return x/sample-folder

Comment: So you call it twice, `os.path.split(os.path.split(__file__)[0])[1]` or use `os.path.split(os.getcwd())[1]`